# Automatic HTML option creator with php doubling output

Tags: php, html

I made a function that calculates the price + percentage of a ticket but it's not quite there.

```
function tickets($maxNumberTickets,$standaardPrice,$AmountOfDiscounts,$DiscountEveryNumberTickets,$percentDiscount){
    for($i = 1; $i <= $maxNumberTickets; $i++) {
        if($i <= $DiscountEveryNumberTickets){
                echo '<option value="' . $i . '">' . $i . ' voor €' . ($standaardPrice * $i) . '</option>';
        }else{
            for($o = 1; $o <= $AmountOfDiscounts; $o++){
                if($i >= ($DiscountEveryNumberTickets* $o)){
                    echo '<option value="' . $i . '">' . $i . ' voor €' . (($standaardPrice * $i) - (($standaardPrice * $i) * ($percentDiscount * $o / 100))) . ' (' . ($percentDiscount * $o) . '% korting)</option>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The call for the function

```
tickets(15,20,3,5,10);
```

Where I say

1. max ticket 15
2. every ticket is a 20€ increase
3. if by any chance the max tickets in increased there will be a max of 3 increases on the discount
4. every 5 tickets there is a (5th parameter) increase discount
5. 10% discount

So this is what I have.

What it does:

```
<select class="TicketsVip" name="Tickets">
    <option value="1">1 voor €20</option>
    <option value="2">2 voor €40</option>
    <option value="3">3 voor €60</option>
    <option value="4">4 voor €80</option>
    <option value="5">5 voor €100</option>
    <option value="6">6 voor €108 (10% discount)</option>
    <option value="7">7 voor €126 (10% discount)</option>
    <option value="8">8 voor €144 (10% discount)</option>
    <option value="9">9 voor €162 (10% discount)</option>
    <option value="10">10 voor €180 (10% discount)</option>
    <option value="10">10 voor €160 (20% discount)</option>
    <option value="11">11 voor €198 (10% discount)</option>
    <option value="11">11 voor €176 (20% discount)</option>
    <option value="12">12 voor €216 (10% discount)</option>
    <option value="12">12 voor €192 (20% discount)</option>
    <option value="13">13 voor €234 (10% discount)</option>
    <option value="13">13 voor €208 (20% discount)</option>
    <option value="14">14 voor €252 (10% discount)</option>
    <option value="14">14 voor €224 (20% discount)</option>
    <option value="15">15 voor €270 (10% discount)</option>
    <option value="15">15 voor €240 (20% discount)</option>
    <option value="15">15 voor €210 (30% discount)</option>
</select>
```

What it should do:

```
<select class="TicketsVip" name="Tickets">
    <option value="1">1 voor €20</option>
    <option value="2">2 voor €40</option>
    <option value="3">3 voor €60</option>
    <option value="4">4 voor €80</option>
    <option value="5">5 voor €100</option>
    <option value="6">6 voor €108 (10% discount)</option>
    <option value="7">7 voor €126 (10% discount)</option>
    <option value="8">8 voor €144 (10% discount)</option>
    <option value="9">9 voor €162 (10% discount)</option>
    <option value="10">10 voor €160 (20% discount)</option>
    <option value="11">11 voor €176 (20% discount)</option>
    <option value="12">12 voor €192 (20% discount)</option>
    <option value="13">13 voor €208 (20% discount)</option>
    <option value="14">14 voor €224 (20% discount)</option>
    <option value="15">15 voor €210 (30% discount)</option>
</select>
```

I tried to change my code but whatever I try doesn't work. The problem is that I get a 10% and a 20% discount for everything above 10, but it should only show the 20% discount.

Has anyone an idea on what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Should you not have one more `option` with 10% discount in the second list?

Comment: `$DiscountEveryNumberTickets = 5` & `$AmountOfDiscounts = 3`. Check the code. Debug it.

Comment: It's suppose to always output the most discount, like every 5 tickets there is a 10% increase and should only show the one with the most discount.

Comment: That is why asked you why do you have only 4 '10% discounts' tickets in what you ant to achieve, and not 5. Your `$DiscountEveryNumberTickets = 5`, right?

Comment: @b0s3 What do you mean?

Comment: By the way you should be careful not to exceed 100% discount :)

Comment: @YasenZhelev The problem isn't that I only have 4 10%'s, the problem is that I have the same option multiple times.

Comment: @YasenZhelev That's why I added the 'AmountOfDiscount' were in this case it is set to 3 & the percentage increase 10 so max 30%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I re-build your function in a new way that at least for me look more clear. And it is working.

Probably it can be refactored to make the code even more readable, but I will leave that to you.

I am usign the 'modulus' operation `%`: http://php.net/language.operators.arithmetic to check if the current ticket iteration number divides exactly by `$DiscountEveryNumberTickets`.

Foe example: 5 % 5 = 0, 10 % 5 = 0, etc.

```
function tickets($maxNumberTickets, $standaardPrice, $AmountOfDiscounts, $DiscountEveryNumberTickets, $percentDiscount){
    $currentDiscount = 0; // our initial discount is 0%
    $discountsSoFar = 1; // we start with the initial discount of 0%
    for($i = 1; $i <= $maxNumberTickets; $i++) {
        if ($i % $DiscountEveryNumberTickets == 0 && $discountsSoFar <= $AmountOfDiscounts)
        {
            // time to apply new discount
            $currentDiscount += $percentDiscount; // increase the discount
            if ($currentDiscount > 100) $currentDiscount = 100; // make sure the discount is not more than 100% :)
            $discountsSoFar ++; // increase the number of discounts so far
        }

        //total price minus the discount
        $tickets_price = ($standaardPrice * $i) - (($standaardPrice * $i) * ($currentDiscount /100)); 

        // show the option according to the current settings
        echo '<option value="' . $i . '">' . $i . ' voor €' . $tickets_price . ($currentDiscount > 0 ? ' ('.$currentDiscount.'% discount)' : '') .'</option>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, like this but `if($i % $DiscountEveryNumberTickets == 0 && $discountsSoFar < $AmountOfDiscounts){` should be `if($i % $DiscountEveryNumberTickets == 0 && $discountsSoFar <= $AmountOfDiscounts){` in order for the 3th discount (15th ticket 30% discount)

Comment: I will explain in the answer and will modify it to work as you requested.